# What does each of these network services do

Tags: init

I have the services listed in the `/etc/init.d` folder starting with 'network':

```
cyrex@cyrex:/etc/init.d$ ls network*
networking                  network-interface-security
network-interface           network-manager
```

What does each of these do. For example which one is related to the gui version of network manager, which one will drop network support for all network cards.

Comment: I hope I got all your questions covered but the 'etc...' is hard to answer ;) If you need more info please edit your q and I'll try to add in as much as I can.

Comment: What package provides the file? `dpkg -S` to the rescue: `dpkg -S /etc/init.d/network*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- What does each of these do?

networking:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          networking
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Should-Start:      ifupdown
# Should-Stop:       ifupdown
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: Raise network interfaces.
### END INIT INFO
```

Regarding the package ifupdown mentioned here: includes commands`ifup` and `ifdown` which may be used to (de)configure network interfaces (`/etc/network/interfaces`).

The other 3 are upstart deamons. From their respective `.conf` files in `/etc/init/`:

network-interface-security:

```
# network-interface-security - configure network device security
#
# This is a one-time start-up script to load AppArmor profiles needed
# before the network comes up.
```

network-interface:

```
# network-interface - configure network device
#
# This service causes network devices to be brought up or down as a result
# of hardware being added or removed, including that which isn't ordinarily
# removable.
```

network-manager:

```
# network-manager - network connection manager
#
# The Network Manager daemon manages the system's network connections,
# automatically switching between the best available.
```

- For example which one is related to the gui version of network manager?

None of these. See the next answer.

- Which one will drop network support for all network cards?

Initiating `networking` will do that but the command used will mostlikely be `ifup --all` and `ifdown --all`. From `man ifup`:

```
-a, --all

If given to ifup, affect all interfaces marked auto. 
Interfaces are brought up in the order in which they are defined in
/etc/network/interfaces. 

If given to ifdown, affect all defined interfaces. 
Interfaces are brought down in the order in which they are currently 
listed in the state file. 
Only interfaces defined in /etc/network/interfaces will be brought down.
```